# How to use variable to dynamically build regular expression object

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to build regular expression on the fly, like:

```
function buildReges(regex_string) {
   // here I want to use the string format to build a regex
   // like / + regex_string +/
}
```

I wonder how can I do that? Or if there is a way I can turn string into regular expression object?

Comment: @Amit THanks, Yes, this is JS, right now, what I can figure out is using JS Regex constructor, but I do not know how to specify /g /i

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor:

```
function buildReges(regex_string) {
   // here I want to use the string format to build a regex
   var re = new RegExp(regex_string);
}
```

if you want to use flags, you use a 2nd parameter:

```
new RegExp(regex_string, 'gi');
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes, this is JS, right now, what I can figure out is using JS Regex constructor, but I do not know how to specify /g /i –

Comment: Thansk, this is helpful